# What should be the values of GOPATH and GOROOT?

Tags: go, gopath

I'm trying to install [doozer](https://github.com/ha/doozer) like this:

```
$ goinstall github.com/ha/doozer
```

I get these errors.

> ```
> goinstall: os: go/build: package could not be found locally
> goinstall: fmt: go/build: package could not be found locally
> goinstall: io: go/build: package could not be found locally
> goinstall: reflect: go/build: package could not be found locally
> goinstall: math: go/build: package could not be found locally
> goinstall: rand: go/build: package could not be found locally
> goinstall: url: go/build: package could not be found locally
> goinstall: net: go/build: package could not be found locally
> goinstall: sync: go/build: package could not be found locally
> goinstall: runtime: go/build: package could not be found locally
> goinstall: strings: go/build: package could not be found locally
> goinstall: sort: go/build: package could not be found locally
> goinstall: strconv: go/build: package could not be found locally
> goinstall: bytes: go/build: package could not be found locally
> goinstall: log: go/build: package could not be found locally
> goinstall: encoding/binary: go/build: package could not be found locally
> ```

Comment: @Motin the above link is no longer valid

Comment: The file became obsolete for the project. A related issue related to OSX is found here: https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/841

Comment: Note: by default, `GOPATH` will be set for you in Go 1.8 (2017). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40238276/6309)

Comment: With Go 1.9 (Q3 2017), you don't need to worry about `GOROOT` anymore. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45529403/6309).

Comment: when I use `goinstall` returned: `goinstall: command not found`, then I use `go install`. why?!

Comment: @BenyaminJafari because `goinstall` is really ancient pre-Go1 and hasn't existed since 2012.

Answer (score 433, accepted):

`GOPATH` is discussed [in the `cmd/go` documentation](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable):

> The `GOPATH` environment variable lists places to look for Go code. On
> Unix, the value is a colon-separated string. On Windows, the value is
> a semicolon-separated string. On Plan 9, the value is a list.
>
> `GOPATH` must be set to get, build and install packages outside the
> standard Go tree.

*Set `GOPATH` to a custom directory for installing downloaded packages.*

`GOROOT` is discussed in [the installation instructions](http://golang.org/doc/install#tarball_non_standard):

> The Go binary distributions assume they will be installed in
> `/usr/local/go` (or `c:\Go` under Windows), but it is possible to install
> the Go tools to a different location. In this case you must set the
> `GOROOT` environment variable to point to the directory in which it was
> installed.
>
> For example, if you installed Go to your home directory you should add
> the following commands to `$HOME/.profile`:
>
> ```
> export GOROOT=$HOME/go
> export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
> ```
>
> **Note:** `GOROOT` must be set only when installing to a custom location.

*As of CY2023, for any modern Go installation, [**do not set/export `GOROOT`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45529403/667301).*

(updated version of [Chris Bunch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7971481/1004889).)

Comment: Much more comprehensive information on GOPATH is at [How to Write Go Code.](http://golang.org/doc/code.html)  A grasp of the information there is required for understanding the `go` command, which is essential for working with Go.  For example the use of `goinstall` in the OP should now be `go get`.

Comment: Also note the actual install path of go.  For example, in a default homebrew setup, homebrew will install go in `/usr/local/Cellar/go/`.  In this case the export path should be set with `export GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/{version}` and `export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin`.

Comment: I had to do `export GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/` to get mine working with brew.

Comment: I can’t suggest this edit because the app complains that my edit “appears to contain” unformatted code (which it doesn’t; thanks a lot SO) but:

Comment: Starting in Go 1.10, if GOROOT is unset the go tool will try to figure it out by its own location.  I also can’t paste the link because paste doesn’t work in Stack Exchange’s iOS app.  Very frustrated right now.

Comment: Interesting that the windows installer puts go.exe in C:\Go\bin but sets GOROOT to `%USERPROFILE%\go` - a directory which doesn't exist.

Comment: I think this is out of date, Go itself defaults to GOPATH being in your homedir: 
`go env GOPATH
$HOME/go
`

Comment: Note on M1, the brew install location for Go (at least for me) is `/opt/homebrew/bin`, not `/usr/local/Cellar/go/`.

Answer (score 141):

Here is a my simple setup:

```
directory for go related things: ~/programming/go
directory for go compiler/tools: ~/programming/go/go-1.4
directory for go software      : ~/programming/go/packages
```

GOROOT, GOPATH, PATH are set as following:

```bash
export GOROOT=/home/user/programming/go/go-1.4
export GOPATH=/home/user/programming/go/packages
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

So, in short:

GOROOT is for compiler/tools that comes from go installation.
GOPATH is for your own go projects / 3rd party libraries (downloaded with "go get").

Comment: I think this answer is easier to understand as there's a mapping against the folder structure.

Comment: Does GOPATH include entire project trees (e.g. git) with non-go files - e.g. images, scripts, build files, etc?

Comment: Can you provide your wall of installation? I assume you used wget to download the tar file and unzip it later?

Comment: what's the difference between "go related things" and "go software"?

Answer (score 96):

First run `go env`.
If you see that the go isn't installed, you can install it via `homebrew` or via package and/or other ways.
If you are seeing output then your `Go` is installed.
It shows you all the envs that are set and are not.

If you see empty for `GOROOT`:

1. Run `which go` (On my computer : `/usr/local/go/bin/go`)
2. then export like this  `export GOROOT=/usr/local/go`

If you see empty for `GOPATH`:

1. Create any directory anywhere on your computer for go projects in my case: `~/GO_PROJECTS`
2. Then `export GOPATH=~/GO_PROJECTS`

Comment: `which go` did it for me. It was using another go installation location from a previous installation using Chocolatey. Deleted that folder and removed it from PATH variable. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: `which go` command did not work for me in Windows 7. How do I find where should I run this command

Comment: The corresponding windows command is `where go` it will show you the path of the executed file

Comment: `export GOPATH=~/GO_PROJECTS` did job

Comment: In WSL2 it `which go` returns `/usr/bin/go`, which is a binary, not a directory. Not sure what to do.

Comment: The `go env` shows the `GOPATH="/home/thanos/go"` however if I check the `env` I don't see that variable. For example I get nothing when I run `echo $GOPATH`. Is that normal ?

Comment: Thank you for this. In my case, I downloaded Go using chocolatey and it was creating my GOROOT in "GOROOT=C:/Program Files/Go". I had to account for the space in the folder name so I ran the command as `export GOROOT=C:/Program\ Files/Go`

Answer (score 44):

`GOPATH` is discussed [here](http://golang.org/cmd/goinstall/):

> The `GOPATH` Environment Variable
>
> `GOPATH` may be set to a colon-separated list of paths inside which Go
>   code, package objects, and executables may be found.
>
> Set a `GOPATH` to use goinstall to build and install your own code and
>   external libraries outside of the Go tree (and to avoid writing
>   Makefiles).

And `GOROOT` is discussed [here](http://golang.org/doc/install.html):

> `$GOROOT` The root of the Go tree, often `$HOME/go`. This defaults to the
>   parent of the directory where `all.bash` is run. If you choose not to
>   set `$GOROOT`, you must run gomake instead of make or gmake when
>   developing Go programs using the conventional makefiles.

Comment: so if I have go installed at ~/projects/go, what should the values of the variable be to find os, fmt, etc?

Comment: So where does Go install when you `sudo apt-get install golang`?

Comment: @weberc2 if you run `go env` you should see that information, for me it was `/usr/lib/go/`

Answer (score 20):

I read the `go help gopath` docs and was still incredibly confused, but found this little nugget from another go doc page:

> The GOPATH environment variable specifies the location of your workspace. It is likely the only environment variable you'll need to set when developing Go code.

http://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH

Answer (score 15):

Starting with go 1.8 (Q2 2017), GOPATH will be set for you by default to $HOME/go

See [issue 17262](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17262) and Rob Pike's comment:

> `$HOME/go` it will be.
> There is no single best answer but this is short and sweet, and it can only be a problem to choose that name if `$HOME/go` already exists, which will only happen for experts who already have go installed and will understand `GOPATH`.

Comment: How can a topic so simple become so complex! Thanks for the best answer here.

Comment: @dodgy_coder Actually... look at the first two lines of my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37905102/6309 ;) That might end up being even simpler: no more GOPATH at all! More details in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48914523/6309.

Comment: yes I agree, GOPATH is not really required if you go with the default, is that correct? I needed to set it anyway due to it being required for the Google App Engine (Go Standard) development environment. They actually tell you to set the GOPATH, but don't tell you what value to set it to..!

Comment: @dodgy_coder Yes, by default, Go will look for the project PATH in a fixed predetermined value.

Answer (score 15):

You generally should not set `GOROOT` explicitly. The `go` command identifies the appropriate `GOROOT` automatically based on its own directory location.

---

`GOPATH` defaults to `$HOME/go`. You only need to set it explicitly if you want to put it somewhere else.

`GOPATH` contains:

- Binaries installed using `go install`, located at `$GOPATH/bin`.¹

  - This location can be overridden using the `GOBIN` environment variable.
- A [cache of downloaded module source code and checksums](https://golang.org/ref/mod#module-cache), located at `$GOPATH/pkg/mod`.

  - This location can be overridden using the `GOMODCACHE` environment variable.

If you set both `GOBIN` and `GOMODCACHE`, and do not set `GO111MODULE=off`, then `GOPATH` itself should have essentially no effect.

---

In addition, in the legacy `GOPATH` mode (when `GO111MODULE=off` is also set), `GOPATH` contains:

- Source code used to build packages, stored in a directory tree rooted at `$GOPATH/src`.
- Non-binaries installed using `go install`, located at `$GOPATH/pkg`.

  - Installing non-binary packages is no longer particularly useful: the `go` command has a [cache of built artifacts](https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Build_and_test_caching), which has been [required since Go 1.12](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.12#gocache) even in `GOPATH` mode.
  - The build cache is *not* located within `GOPATH`. Its location can be set with the `GOCACHE` environment variable.

---

¹ Binaries can also be installed using `go get` on Go 1.17 and earlier, but `go install` is preferred as of Go 1.16; see https://golang.org/doc/go1.16.

Comment: The [cache of built artifacts](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go@master#hdr-Build_and_test_caching) link is no longer valid.

Answer (score 13):

The GOPATH should *not* point to the Go installation, but rather to your workspace (see https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH). Whenever you install some package with go get or go install, it will land within the GOPATH. That is why it warns you, that you most definitely do *not* want random packages from the internet to be dumped into your official installation.

Answer (score 9):

Regarding `GOROOT` specifically, Go 1.9 will set it automatically to its installation path.
Even if you have multiple Go installed, calling the 1.9.x one will set `GOROOT` to `/path/to/go/1.9` (before, if not set, it assumed a default path like `/usr/local/go` or `c:\Go`).

See [CL Go Review 53370](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/53370):

> **The [`go tool`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/) will now use the path from which it was invoked to attempt to locate the root of the Go install tree**.
>   This means that if the entire Go installation is moved to a new location, the `go tool` should continue to work as usual.
>
> This may be overriden by setting `GOROOT` in the environment, which should only be done in unusual circumstances.
>   Note that this does not affect the result of the [`runtime.GOROOT()` function](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOROOT), which will continue to report the original installation location; this may be fixed in later releases.

Answer (score 9):

In modern Go, you don't need to set `GOPATH` or `GOROOT`. In fact, unless you're doing something very specialized, it's best to have them unset on your system.

**Use Go modules**. [Having installed Go](https://golang.org/doc/install), pick a directory where you want to work. Then:

```
$ mkdir example
$ cd example
$ go mod init example.com
```

Note that the module name `example.com` is arbitrary; if you keep your work on GitHub, this could be something like `github.com/your-username/project-name`.

The last command will have created a `go.mod` file; now you can grab dependencies with `go get`:

```
$ go get rsc.io/quote
```

Now your code using this dependency:

```
$ touch main.go
```

Place this in `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "rsc.io/quote"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(quote.Go())
}
```

And run with:

```
$ go run .
```

W.r.t. original question, you can now get your `doozer` dependency with:

```
$ go get github.com/ha/doozer
```

Now you can use the `doozer` module in your code. And so on. You can also examine the `go.mod` file in your directory to see the dependencies listed, along with their versions. Each module is self-contained, with its own versions of dependencies. You can have two modules alongside each other, each with its own `go.mod` file pointing to different versions of some dependency - this will all work OK because of the isolation between modules.

For additional information, start with [the official tutorial here](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started). In several chapters, it walks you through the steps shown above, as well as writing your own reusable modules and packages, and importing them from other modules. Additional interactive tutorials are available at https://play-with-go.dev/

Answer (score 8):

`GOPATH` and `GOROOT` configurations are deprecated.

You can use the GO module instead.

For example:

```
mkdir go_app
cd go_app
go mod init go_app
```

Comment: For most cases naming your module `go_app` will be ok, but it is more correct provide full path to you project. For example `github.com/username/projectname`.

Comment: I think you mean **deprecated**.

Comment: @ont.rif Why it is more correct as soon as I am not going to publish my code ?

Comment: @thanos.a in such case it is ok, but name of package must not override name of standart go modules. With full path it is easier to avoid such situations.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned above:

> The GOPATH environment variable specifies the location of your
>   workspace.

**For Windows**, this worked for me (in Ms-dos window):

```
set GOPATH=D:\my_folder_for_go_code\
```

This creates a GOPATH variable that Ms-dos recognizes when used as follows:

```
cd %GOPATH%
```

Answer (score 5):

Lots of answers but no substance, like robots doing cut and paste on what's on their system. There is no need to set `GOROOT` as an environment variable. However, there is a **beneficial** need to set the `GOPATH` environment variable, and if not set it defaults to `${HOME}/go/` folder.

It is the `PATH` environment variable that you must pay attention because this variable is the variable that can change your `go version`. Not `GOROOT`! Forget `GOROOT`.

Now, if you switch or change to a new `go version`, your downloaded packages will use the default `$HOME/go` folder and it will mixed-up with whatever your previous `go version` was. This is not good.

Therefore, this is where `GOPATH` you need to define in order to isolate downloaded packages of the new `go version`.

In summary, forget `GOROOT`. Think more on `GOPATH`.

Answer (score 2):

Run `go help environment` it has documentation for every environment variable that can be listed by `go env` command

Answer (score 2):

There's a command you can use: `go env GOPATH`

Comment: This was helpful but I could use a little more help on how I could use it to better understand best practices and the consequences of following and not following them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution (single user):

```
GOROOT=$HOME/.local # your go executable is in $GOROOT/bin
GOPATH=$HOME/.gopath
PATH=$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
```

`go` complains if you change `.gopath` to `.go`.

I wish they went with how the `rust/cargo` guys did and just put everything at one place.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly set `GOROOT` (Modern versions of Go can figure it out on their own based on the location of the go binary that you run).

Also, got the follow error when trying to work with `vgo`:

```
go: modules disabled inside GOPATH/src by GO111MODULE=auto; see 'go help modules'
```

Removing GOROOT, updating my GOPATH and `export GO111MODULE="on"` resolved the issue.

GOPATH see in [here](http://golang.org/cmd/goinstall/)

> GOPATH may be set to a colon-separated list of paths inside which Go code, package objects, and executables may be found.
>
> Set a GOPATH to use goinstall to build and install your own code and external libraries outside of the Go tree (and to avoid writing Makefiles).

Comment: Upvoting for correctly stating that there is no need to explicitly setting `GOROOT` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020 and Go version 1.13+, in Windows the best way for updating GOPATH is just typing in command prompt:

```
setx GOPATH C:\mynewgopath
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to append

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10.1/libexec
```

to my *~/.bash_profile* on Mac OS X

Answer (score -1):

There is also a case where when we use go it compiles all the go files.

So lets say we had one file *main.go* and later we changed the current file to *main_old.go* and then added our new *main.go* file. Then when we build our app all the go files will get compiled. So the error that's happening might be due to compilation error in some other go files.

Answer (score -1):

Once Go lang is installed, GOROOT is the root directory of the installation.

When I exploded Go Lang binary in Windows C:\ directory, my GOROOT should be C:\go.
If Installed with Windows installer, it may be C:\Program Files\go (or C:\Program Files (x86)\go, for 64-bit packages)

```
 GOROOT = C:\go
```

while my GOPATH is location of Go lang source code or workspace.

If my Go lang source code is located at C:\Users\\GO_Workspace, your GOPATH would be as below:

```
 GOPATH = C:\Users\<xyz>\GO_Workspace
```

Answer (score -1):

For all newcomers they could do a simply `export GOPATH=$HOME/go` if you are using Ubuntu or do `go help gopath` for more information.

Answer (score -2):

in osx, i installed with brew, here is the setting that works for me

```
GOPATH="$HOME/my_go_work_space" //make sure you have this folder created

GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10/libexec"
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are using the distro go, you should point to where the include files are, for example:

```
$ rpm -ql golang | grep include
/usr/lib/golang/include
```

(This is for Fedora 20)

Answer (score -3):

the values should be (MACOS):

```
GOROOT="/usr/local/go" --> all binaries file core go
GOPATH="/Applications/proyectos/go" --> the route to workspace (custom workspace)
```