# unable to run goinstall

Tags: go, goinstall

```
goinstall go-tour.googlecode.com/hg/gotour
```

Running the above command give me the following message ..

```
goinstall: encoding/json: go/build: package could not be found locally
goinstall: code.google.com/p/go-tour/pic: cannot download: code.google.com/p/go-tour/pic
goinstall: code.google.com/p/go-tour/tree: cannot download: code.google.com/p/go-tour/tree
goinstall: code.google.com/p/go-tour/wc: cannot download: code.google.com/p/go-tour/wc
goinstall: os/exec: go/build: package could not be found locally
goinstall: net/http: go/build: package could not be found locally
```

I know that there is problem with path setting .. i also checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970390/what-should-be-the-values-of-gopath-and-goroot)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/sakthi/sakthig/code/my/go/go/bin
export GOROOT=/home/sakthi/sakthig/code/my/go/go
export GOPATH=$GOROOT/bin
```

This is my current path setting.. any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Go Tour project](http://code.google.com/p/go-tour/) has been updated recently.

The Go [weekly.2011-11-09](http://weekly.golang.org/doc/devel/weekly.html#2011-11-09) release renamed the `json` package to `encoding/json`.

The Go [weekly.2011-12-14](http://weekly.golang.org/doc/devel/weekly.html#2011-12-14) release changed the naming for the `go-tour` package `import` paths from `"go-tour.googlecode.com/hg/tree"` to `"code.google.com/p/go-tour/tree"`.

Update to the Go weekly release ([Keeping up with releases](http://golang.org/doc/install.html#releases)).

```
$ cd $GOROOT/src
$ hg pull
$ hg update weekly
$ ./all.bash
```

Then install the `go-tour/tree` package.

```
$ cd $GOROOT
$ goinstall -v -fix code.google.com/p/go-tour/tree
goinstall: open /home/peter/go/goinstall.log: no such file or directory
goinstall: code.google.com/p/go-tour/tree: download
goinstall: cd / && /usr/bin/hg clone https://code.google.com/p/go-tour /home/peter/go/src/pkg/code.google.com/p/go-tour
goinstall: selecting tip
goinstall: cd /home/peter/go/src/pkg/code.google.com/p/go-tour && /usr/bin/hg update
goinstall: code.google.com/p/go-tour/tree: install
goinstall: cd /home/peter/go/src/pkg/code.google.com/p/go-tour/tree && /bin/bash gomake -f- install
$
```

Comment: `hg update weekly` This command helped .. before this i used to try `hg update release` which dint work or at least dint solve my problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

Specifically in the weekly.2011-12-14, goinstall was updated to reject google paths that don't follow the format:  "code.google.com/p/go-tour/tree"

This format would fail:  "go-tour.googlecode.com/hg/tree"

Actual release information:
http://goo.gl/PeXnO

Comment: i tried and ended with same error message `go/build: package could not be found locally`

Comment: Did ~go/src/all.bash reported any problems? Also check if you're not mixing binaries versions. Look e.g. at/if exists ~/go/bin, ~/bin, ... if there are any Go binaries and check their versions and compare with your PATH. Perhaps try w/o GOPATH set. Try `$(which 6g) -V`. It must be something simple, but I'm out of ideas :-(

Comment: @Sakti - not sure what the problem is then. I just updated my go to the current weekly and ran `goinstall -v -clean -u -nuke code.google.com/p/go-tour/tree` with no problem

Comment: @jnml - good question. is it possible he didnt run all.bash after updating the repo?

Comment: go-tour project **is** compatible with r60. Perhaps consult more steps on golang-nuts, I give up, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ goinstall go-tour.googlecode.com/hg/gotour
go-tour.googlecode.com/hg/gotour: download failed: unsupported import path;
should be "code.google.com/p/go-tour/gotour"
Run goinstall with -fix to gofix the code. ($GOPATH is not set)
$ goinstall -dashboard=false code.google.com/p/go-tour/gotour
$ (cd ~/go && hg id)
82fdc445f2ff weekly/weekly.2011-12-14
$
```

Comment: This is what i get by running above line                           `$ goinstall -dashboard=false code.google.com/p/go-tour/gotour -fix
goinstall: code.google.com/p/go-tour/gotour: cannot download: code.google.com/p/go-tour/gotour
goinstall: -fix: go/build: package could not be found locally`

Comment: `package not found locally` is constant in all goinstall commands

Comment: You're probably running a different version of Go. Additionally, if no other goinstall command succeeds then there's probably also some other problem not related to the version of Go. Can you try to switch to latest weekly and reproduce the OK pass as above?

Comment: I installed go merely 4 hours ago.. can u show your path settings ? I suspect that may be the problem ??

Comment: `17:48:58 jnml@shinigami:~$ env | grep GO`

`GOBIN=/home/jnml/bin`

`GOROOT=/home/jnml/go`

`17:48:59 jnml@shinigami:~$`

Comment: Never used GOPATH for anything. Actually I don't even know for sure what it is good for ;-)

Comment: Setting gopath is for installing to different locations such as when you want to have libs located outside the go source tree