# How to install golang 3rd-party projects from download sources?

Tags: installation, go, mgo

I'm trying to install [mgo](http://labix.org/mgo) which is a mongo-driver written in golang.

The standard command:

```
go get launchpad.net/mgo
```

But it failed because of some cert issues.

So I manually download the sources of mgo to local `E:\mgo`, but I don't know to how install it.

The file tree:

```
├─.bzr
│  ├─branch
│  │  └─lock
│  ├─branch-lock
│  ├─checkout
│  │  └─lock
│  └─repository
│      ├─indices
│      ├─lock
│      ├─obsolete_packs
│      ├─packs
│      └─upload
├─bson
└─testdb
```

I tried:

```
cd mgo
go install
```

It reports:

```
auth.go:34:2: import "launchpad.net/mgo/bson": cannot find package
```

But if I try to install bson first:

```
cd bson
go install
```

It reports another error:

```
go install: no install location for _/E_/mgo/bson
```

So, what's the correct command to install it?

Comment: Are your projects in your GOPATH env variable ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Finally I successfully install the mgo project. I think it will be helpful for beginners, so I answer it here.

**First, we need GOPATH**

Define a env variable `GOPATH`, which is your project root directory, and it should have a sub dir `src`.

For me, I define it to `E:\WORKSPACE_GO\mgo`, then create a sub dir `src`

**Copy the project to the src**

Then copy the `mgo` project to `%GOPATH%/mgo`, but we must be careful about the directory structure. It should be exactly the same as the package defined in sources.

For `mgo`, it's package is `launchpad.net/mgo`, so the structure should be:

```
E:\WORKSPACE_GO\mgo\src\launchpad.net\mgo
```

**go install**

At last, `go install` them:

```
cd E:\WORKSPACE_GO\mgo\src\launchpad.net\mgo\bson
go install

cd ..
go install
```

If there is no error input, it should be successfully installed.

Comment: You can have multiple projects in your GOPATH. I usually have the standard Go repository, a go directory where I put all my external imports (from code.google.com or github.com), and all my go projects. The go tool always put the compiled things in the nearest gopath directory and always find the imports.

Comment: Freewind, you can accept your answer.  It's basically correct.  The best documentation for GOPATH is http://golang.org/doc/code.html#tmp_13.  You generally don't have to do your first step there if you have set up GOPATH previously.  You leave it the same way as you work on different projects.  Your copy step is correct.  For go install, you don't have to install dependencies separately.  You can just install the top-level commands or packages and all of the dependencies will be installed automatically.

Comment: You don’t need to `go install` it. As long as any project depending on that package has that GOPATH in its GOPATH (in GOPATH when building), it will find the dependency anyway. In fact, if it can find the `go install`-generated files, it will also find the sources and build it for itself if necessary.

Comment: Also one must note that Bazaar must be installed and available in PATH.

Answer (score 29):

[Set](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH) [GOPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970390/what-should-be-the-values-of-gopath-and-goroot). Move code under `$GOPATH`. Then

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/user/package
go get .
```

Explanation:

```
go build .    # produces binary in current dir 
go install .  # produces binary in $GOPATH/bin 
go get .      # same as 'install' but resolves import deps
```

[More on that](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/_l6HBdrz1Fc/PPXVOOHJ2aAJ)

Comment: I get no buildable Go source files in "said directory."

Answer (score 5):

You will have to **put it into your `GOPATH/src` directory**, preserving the import path (the one you passed to `go install`).

The fallback GOPATH is your **go install directory**. So you can clone the *mgo* repository to `go/src/pkg/launchpad.net/mgo`.

Alternatively, when you set up a project directory/environment **for your project** that depends on mgo, and set the `GOPATH` environment variable to that *FOLDER*, then you can clone the *mgo* repository to `FOLDER/src/launchpad.net/mgo/`.

You can then use the mgo package in your project as expected:

```
import "launchpad.net/mgo"
```

Answer (score 0):

The fly in the ointment of all this, is that GOPATH is a *path* - similar to Java's classpath, or Unix's PATH. It is not a single directory location: it is a sequence of directory locations. E.g., I routinely uses statements of the form,

```
GOPATH=dira:dirb:dirc go install mypackage
```