# Go: error on import in hello world

Tags: go

My test program `test.go`:

```
package main

import "fmt"
func main() {
  fmt.Printf("Hello\n")
}
```

Running this `go run test.go` finishes with errors:

```
# io
pack: cannot open $WORK/io/_obj/_go_.6
# strconv
pack: cannot open $WORK/strconv/_obj/_go_.6
```

Environment:

```
go version devel +715674f61ae8 Tue Jan 29 13:34:18 2013 -0800 linux/amd64

GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/usr/local/google/home/igord/incub/web"
GOROOT="/opt/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/opt/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

But I downloaded this version from (featured) *RELEASE 1.0.3* on the go site!

Comment: What's the output of `go env`?

Comment: Did you install Go to an unusual location? What are your $GOROOT and $GOPATH? See http://golang.org/doc/install#install

Comment: What is the output of `go env`? What is the output of `go run -work test.go`?

Comment: For `go run -work test.go`: `WORK=/tmp/go-build437772438` and rest is the same.

Comment: @RichChurcher You are right. I put go to `/opt`. After I moved it to `/usr/local/` everything works fine. But note I made `GOROOT` to point installation path.

Comment: Good to hear it's working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by various in comments, but for the record: installing a binary distribution of Go to a location other than the default requires setting `$GOROOT` and `$GOPATH` correctly.

- [Getting Started: Install the Go tools](http://golang.org/doc/install#install)
- Related: [what should be the values of GOPATH and GOROOT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970390/what-should-be-the-values-of-gopath-and-goroot)