# How to install the current version of Go in Ubuntu Precise

Tags: ubuntu, go

Running `sudo apt-get install golang-stable`, I get Go version `go1.0.3`. Is there any way to install `go1.1.1`?

Comment: In the end I had to install from source. Not all tests passed but it seems to be working ok.

Comment: "Not all tests passed but it seems to be working ok."

@sofia what version of Ubuntu are you using? I would not expect test failures unless you were running a very old version of Ubuntu or you accidentally installed "tip" vs. "stable".

Comment: I'm using ubuntu precise. But installing the latest version from the repo duh/golang didn't report any problem, so not sure what the problem was.

Comment: I am also using precise. Did you run "hg update tip" or "hg update release". If you don't recall look back in your bash history file. Using tip might explain the test failures.

Comment: You can try this blog http://railskey.wordpress.com/2014/05/31/install-gogolang-on-ubuntu/

Comment: As of July 2014, I used `apt-get install -f gccgo-go`

Comment: It's precompiled for linux 32/64, just untar it: http://golang.org/doc/install#tarball and update your `PATH`

Comment: Related: [Updating golang on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/720260/78223).

Answer (score 164, accepted):

[Updated (previous answer no longer applied)]

For fetching the latest version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/golang-backports
sudo apt update
sudo apt install golang-go
```

Also see the [wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu)

Comment: So as of 2014 July, this no longer has the latest version of Go. Current version is 1.3. After trying this on Ubuntu 12.04, I ended up with version 1.1.1.

Comment: Please update this. As of Sep 2014, I also end up with "go1.1.2"

Comment: As of 2014-10-24, I got 1.2.1 linux/amd64.

Comment: Checking in on March 29th, 2015. That ppa responds with a 404.

Comment: I used ``ppa:evarlast/golang1.4``

Comment: As of October 2015, **sudo apt-get install golang** is still not uptodate. It installed version 1.2.1.

Comment: I don't know if it's a good idea to add unknown community repos willy-nilly
It's probably better to install directly from the go website.
https://golang.org/dl/
https://golang.org/doc/install
Be sure to uninstall the old version first.
https://golang.org/doc/install#uninstall

Comment: This `export GOBIN=/usr/bin/go` seems like not what you want to do. `export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin` or `export GOBIN=$HOME/workspace/go/bin` seems more likely.

Comment: @jorfus The problem with installing directly as recommended at golang.org is that there is no automatic update mechanism to fix security issues. See [software installation - How to install a recent, managed version of golang on Ubuntu 14.04? - Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/847867/how-to-install-a-recent-managed-version-of-golang-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: `Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~duh/ubuntu/golang'. The user named '~duh' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/golang'.`

Comment: As of August 2020, You need not add the ppa repo. Just use `sudo apt  install golang-go` (For Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: software-properties-common

Answer (score 104):

I like to use [GVM](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm) for managing my Go versions in my Ubuntu box.  Pretty simple to use, and if you're familiar with RVM, it's a nobrainer.  It allows you to have multiple versions of Go installed in your system and switch between whichever version you want at any point in time.

Install GVM with:

```
sudo apt-get install bison mercurial
bash < <(curl -LSs 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moovweb/gvm/master/binscripts/gvm-installer')
. "$HOME/.gvm/scripts/gvm"
```

and then it's as easy as doing this:

```
gvm install go1.1.1
gvm use go1.1.1 --default
```

The default flag at the end of the second command will set go1.1.1 to be your default Go version whenever you start a new terminal session.

Comment: I like RVM and always enjoy a good tool in my kit. Glad to see as I get into Go that there's a tool like GVM :)

Comment: gvm is same name as for grails gvm

Comment: I just tried using GVM under the fish shell, and a warning to those who don't use bash: GVM will be a pain to get up and running properly. A lot of its scripts don't have a shebang line for example.

Comment: the "GVM" web page referenced `https://github.com/moovweb/gvmt` is 404 not found. And I'm reluctant to install anything that doesn't seem to have its own security update procedure

Comment: I do not agree that it's as easy as "gvm install" and "gvm use".

Answer (score 44):

I used following commands from **GoLang official repository**,
it installed **GoLang version 1.6** on my Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-lxc/lxd-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install golang
```

However, since this answer was created, the instructions have been updated to these, for Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 or 22.04 (amd64, arm64 or armhf):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/golang-backports
sudo apt update
sudo apt install golang-go
```

Reference official GoLang Repo https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu it seems this ppa will always be updated in future.

Comment: `The team named '~ubuntu-lxc' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/lxd-stable'`

Comment: From referenced link:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/golang-backports`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install golang-go`

Answer (score 27):

**[October 2015]**
*Answer because the current accepted answer`sudo apt-get install golang` isn't uptodate and if you don't want to install `GVM` follow these steps.*

### Step by step installation:

1. Download the latest version [here](https://golang.org/dl/) (OS: Linux).
2. Open your terminal and go to your Downloads directory
3. `sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go$VERSION.$OS-$ARCH.tar.gz`
4. Add `go` to your path `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`
5. `go version` to check the current version installed
6. Start programming.

### Possible errors + fixes: (to be updated)

If you get a `go version xgcc (Ubuntu 4.9.1-0ubuntu1) 4.9.1 linux/amd64` then you did something wrong, so check out this post: [Go is printing xgcc version but not go installed version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514456/go-is-printing-xgcc-version-but-not-go-installed-version)

Comment: this doesnt have armv7

Answer (score 18):

i installed from source. there is a step-by-step tutorial here: http://golang.org/doc/install/source

Comment: yes. Installing Go from source is the best way to "Go". It is very easy to update that way as well.

Comment: I followed the instructions from here and it worked for me really nice   http://golang.org/doc/install#tarball

Comment: Thank you so much. Still working on my Ubuntu 14.04 while the PPAs don't. :-)

Comment: This is annoying now that you have to bootstrap 1.5+ with a 1.4+ build.

Answer (score 11):

### I use this instruction to install the latest version of <sub>[image: IMG:]</sub>

1. Remove the existing Go version:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge golang*
   ```
2. Install the latest version of Go:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/golang-backports
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install golang-go
   ```
3. Create the `.profile` file in the home path with this content:

   ```
   # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
   # This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
   # exists.
   # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
   # the files are located in the bash-doc package.

   # the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
   # for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
   #umask 022

   # if running bash
   if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
       # include .bashrc if it exists
       if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
           . "$HOME/.bashrc"
       fi
   fi

   # set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
   PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
   ```
4. Set Go workspace to the environment variable:

   ```
   GOPATH=~/.go
   ```
5. Apply the `.profile` configuration:

   ```
   source ~/.profile
   ```

---

Test:

```
$ go version
go version go1.11.1 linux/amd64
```

---

Ref: [Go-GitHub-Installation](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu)

Answer (score 9):

Here is the most straight forward and simple method I found to install go on Ubuntu 14.04 without any ppa or any other tool.

As of now, The version of GO is 1.7

Get the Go 1.7.tar.gz using wget

`wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz`

Extract it and copy it to `/usr/local/`

`sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzvf go1.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz`

You have now successfully installed GO. Now You have to set Environment Variables so you can use the `go` command from anywhere.

To achieve this we need to add a line to `.bashrc`
So,

`sudo nano ~/.bashrc`

and add the following line to the end of file.

`export PATH="/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH"`

Now, All the commands in `go/bin` will work.

Check if the install was successful by doing

`go version`

For offline Documentation you can do

`godoc -http=:6060`

Offline documentation will be available at `http://localhost:6060`

NOTE:

Some people here are suggesting to change the PATH variable.

It is not a good choice.

1. Changing that to `/usr/local/go/bin` is temporary and it'll reset once you close terminal.
2. `go` command will only work in terminal in which you changed the value of PATH.
3. You'll not be able to use any other command like `ls, nano` or just about everything because everything else is in `/usr/bin` or in other locations. All those things will stop working and it'll start giving you error.

However, this is permanent and does not disturbs anything else.

Comment: you need to define env var GOPATH=/some/dir    then define  PATH=${GOPATH}/bin:${PATH}   for your own project code

Comment: Yes, I use VSCode so to add GOPATH I just need to edit gopath in user settings json. Thanks for the input.

Comment: There's a small typo in the tar command: am64 instead of amd64

Comment: @AdrianLungu Fixed it.

Comment: sudo nano ~./bashrc -> sudo nano ~/.bashrc

.. also should be vim :p

Comment: @GameKyuubi Fixed, Thank You!

Comment: remember to restart your terminal, otherwise the changes to bashrc are not applied.

Comment: @Pfinnn you don't need to restart terminal. You just need to reload bashrc. You can do that with, `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 6):

For the current release of Go:

> [The Go Programming Language](http://golang.org/)
>
> [Getting Started](http://golang.org/doc/install)
>
> [Download the Go distribution](http://golang.org/doc/install#download)
>
> [Downloads](https://golang.org/dl/)
>
> Click the link above to visit the Go project's downloads page and
> select the binary distribution that matches your operating system and
> processor architecture.
>
> Official binary distributions are available for the FreeBSD,
> Linux, macOS, and Windows
> operating systems and the 32-bit (386) and 64-bit (amd64) x86
> processor architectures.
>
> If a binary distribution is not available for your combination of
> operating system and architecture you may want to try installing from
> source or installing gccgo instead of gc.
>
> [Installing Go from source](http://golang.org/doc/install/source)

Comment: Installing from source is actually really fast. It compiles fast and the tests are optional if you choose to skip them.

Answer (score 6):

If someone is looking for installing Go 1.8 the follow this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/golang-backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install golang-go
```

And then install go

```
sudo apt-get install golang-1.8-go
```

Comment: Works flawless for me. Thanks!

Comment: No need to install `golang-1.8-go`, it's already installed when installing `golang-go`. Actually as of end April 2017, go **1.8.1** is installed, the latest version.

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu

Comment: I guess you also need to set up GOROOT, GOPATH

Comment: Reference for GOROOT and GOPATH setting right in other answers 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/34384978/248616 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480044/how-to-install-the-current-version-of-go-in-ubuntu-precise#comment65480082_39052584

More official reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/10847122/248616

Comment: For each of our Go project, set GOPATH=/some/dir, PATH=${GOPATH}/bin:${PATH}

Comment: With GOROOT set in .bashrc 
`export GOROOT=/usr/local/bin/go`

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Download say, `go1.6beta1.linux-amd64.tar.gz` from https://golang.org/dl/
>      into `/tmp`

`wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.6beta1.linux-amd64.tar.gz -o /tmp/go1.6beta1.linux-amd64.tar.gz`

> 2. un-tar into `/usr/local/bin`

`sudo tar -zxvf go1.6beta1.linux-amd64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin/`

> 3. Set GOROOT, GOPATH, [on ubuntu add following to ~/.bashrc]

`mkdir ~/go
export GOPATH=~/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export GOROOT=/usr/local/bin/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin`

> 4. Verify

`go version` should show be

> `go version go1.6beta1 linux/amd64`

`go env` should show be

> `GOARCH="amd64"
>   GOBIN=""
>   GOEXE=""
>   GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
>   GOHOSTOS="linux"
>   GOOS="linux"
>   GOPATH="/home/vats/go"
>   GORACE=""
>   GOROOT="/usr/local/bin/go"
>   GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/bin/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
>   GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
>   CC="gcc"
>   GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
>   CXX="g++"
>   CGO_ENABLED="1"`

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer, I am following all the steps but whenever I call "go version" instead of 1.7 it bring 1.4.2 . Is there any other actions that should be done ?

Answer (score 4):

These days according to the [golang github with for Ubuntu](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu), it's possible to install the latest version of Go easily via a snap:

> Using snaps also works quite well:

```
# This will give you the latest version of go
$ sudo snap install --classic go
```

Potentially preferable to fussing with outdated and/or 3rd party PPAs

Answer (score 2):

On recent Ubuntu (20.10) `sudo apt-get install golang` works fine; it will install version 1.14.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you could use [this script](https://github.com/geosoft1/tools) to install Go and LiteIDE?

If you are unhappy with the answer provided, please comment instead of blindly down voting. I have used this setup for the last 4 years without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the update-golang script:

[update-golang](https://github.com/udhos/update-golang) is a script to easily fetch and install new Golang releases with minimum system intrusion

```
git clone https://github.com/udhos/update-golang
cd update-golang
sudo ./update-golang.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question in 2022 it is almost more that 9 years. But I think it is important to automatize this installation.

#### Requirements:

- This was tested on Ubuntu 18 and 20.
- Sudoer user, you must be able to use `sudo`.

#### Installation:

1. Create a new file using this command:

```bash
touch ~/go-installer.sh
```

2. Edit the file using any of editor available i.e., vi, vim, or nano.

```bash
nano ~/go-installer.sh
```

3. Past this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

## Define version and build
VERSION=1.19
BUILD=4

## Define package name
PKG_NAME='go'

## Define go official url
GO_URL='https://golang.org/dl/'

## Define local path
LOCAL_PATH='/usr/local'

## Define system library path
LIB_PATH='/usr/lib'

## Define system binary path
BIN_PATH='/usr/bin'

## Define EV script filename
EV_FILE='/etc/profile.d/go-bin-path.sh'

## Defile export path command
EXPORT_CMD='export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin'

## Define script content
SCRIPT='#!/bin/sh\n'${EXPORT_CMD}

## Define user home dir
USER_HOME_DIR=$(getent passwd ${SUDO_USER:-$USER} | cut -d: -f6)

check_command() {
    [ -x "$(command -v $PKG_NAME)" ] && echo 0 || echo 1
}

test_package() {
    echo
    code=$(check_command)
    [ $code -eq 0 ] && go version || echo "Error: $PKG_NAME is not installed." >&2
    exit $code
}

is_sudoer() {
    ## Define error code
    E_NOTROOT=87 # Non-root exit error.

    ## check if is sudoer
    if ! $(sudo -l &>/dev/null); then
        echo 'Error: root privileges are needed to run this script'
        return $E_NOTROOT
    fi
    return 0
}

if is_sudoer; then
    ## Remove previous package versions
    status="$(dpkg-query -W --showformat='${db:Status-Status}' ${PKG_NAME} 2>&1)"
    if [ $? = 0 ] || [ "${status}" = installed ]; then
        sudo apt remove --purge --auto-remove -y "${PKG_NAME}"
    fi

    pkg_path="${LOCAL_PATH}/go"
    pkg_lib_path="${LIB_PATH}/go"

    ## Download the latest version available.
    [ "$BUILD" -eq "0" ] && version_build="${VERSION}" || version_build="${VERSION}.${BUILD}"
    mkdir "${USER_HOME_DIR}/tmp"
    cd "${USER_HOME_DIR}/tmp"
    wget "${GO_URL}go${version_build}.linux-amd64.tar.gz"

    ## Extract and install the downloaded version
    if [ -f "go${version_build}.linux-amd64.tar.gz" ]; then
        sudo rm -rf "${pkg_path}" && sudo tar -xzvf "go${version_build}.linux-amd64.tar.gz" -C "${LOCAL_PATH}"

        ## Add symbolic link binary files to system binary and library directories
        if [ ! -h "${pkg_lib_path}" ]; then
            sudo ln -sv "${pkg_path}" "${pkg_lib_path}"
        fi

        binaries='go gofmt'
        for i in $binaries; do
            if [ ! -h "${BIN_PATH}/${i}" ]; then
                sudo ln -sv "${pkg_lib_path}/bin/${i}" "${BIN_PATH}/${i}"
            fi
        done

        ## Test your new version.
        test_package
    else
        echo "Error: tar file does not exits." >&2
        exit 1
    fi
else
    exit $?
fi
```

4. Give running permission to the file:

```bash
sudo chmod -v u+x ~/go-installer.sh
```

5. Run the script:

```
./go-installer.sh
```

It will return something like this:

```bash
...
go/test/used.go
go/test/utf.go
go/test/varerr.go
go/test/varinit.go
go/test/winbatch.go
go/test/writebarrier.go
go/test/zerodivide.go
'/usr/lib/go' -> '/usr/local/go'
'/usr/bin/go' -> '/usr/lib/go/bin/go'
'/usr/bin/gofmt' -> '/usr/lib/go/bin/gofmt'

go version go1.19.4 linux/amd64
teocci@ubuntu:~$
```

6. Test your installation:

```bash
go version
```

Now Go will be global and can run from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/golang-backports`
`sudo apt update`
`sudo apt install golang-go`

After above commands and go environment setup
You tried to run a go program it will show you `go: no such tool "compile"`
if you are facing a same then follow below link
`https://stackoverflow.com/a/76550511/22128545`

Comment: Please refrain from copying other answers since it doesn't add any value.

Answer (score -1):

1. If you have ubuntu-mate, you can install latest go by:

   umake go
2. I have a script to download and install the last go from official website

   ```
    # Change these varialbe to where ever you feel comfortable
    DOWNLOAD_DIR=${HOME}/Downloads/GoLang
    INSTALL_DIR=${HOME}/App
    function install {
       mkdir -p ${DOWNLOAD_DIR}
       cd ${DOWNLOAD_DIR}

       echo "Fetching latest Go version..."
       typeset VER=`curl -s https://golang.org/dl/ | grep -m 1 -o 'go\([0-9]\)\+\(\.[0-9]\)\+'`
       if uname -m | grep 64 > /dev/null; then
           typeset ARCH=amd64
       else
           typeset ARCH=386
       fi
       typeset FILE=$VER.linux-$ARCH

       if [[ ! -e ${FILE}.tar.gz ]]; then
            echo "Downloading '$FILE' ..."
            wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/${FILE}.tar.gz
       fi

       echo "Installing ${FILE} ..."
       tar zxfC ${FILE}.tar.gz ${INSTALL_DIR}
       echo "Go is installed"
   }

   install
   ```

Setup your GOROOT, GOPATH and PATH:

```
export GOROOT=${INSTALL_DIR}/go
export GOPATH=<your go path>
export PATH=${PATH}:${GOROOT}/bin:${GOPATH}/bin
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a script from [`udhos/update-golang`](https://github.com/udhos/update-golang).

Here is a two-liner as example (run as `root`):

```
bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/udhos/update-golang/master/update-golang.sh)
ln -vs /usr/local/go/bin/go* /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way to install Go on Ubuntu is to download required version from [here](https://golang.org/dl/). Here you could have all stable and releases, along with archived versions.

after downloading you selected version you can follow further steps, i will suggest you to download tar.gz format for ubuntu machine:

1. first of all fully remove the older version from your local by doing this

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go /usr/local/gocache`

this will remove all the local go code base but wait something more we have to do to remove fully from local, i was missing this step and it took so much time until I understood what i am missing so here is the purge stuff to remove from list

> ```
> sudo apt-get purge golang
> ```

or

> ```
> sudo apt remove golang-go
> ```

2. Now install / extract your downloaded version of go inside /usr/local/go, by hitting terminal with this

> `tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.10.8.linux-amd64.tar.gz`

3. after doing all above stuff , don't forget or check to `GOROOT` variable value you can check the value by `go env` if not set then `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go`
4. Better to test a small go program to make sure. write this inside `/home/yourusername/go/test.php` if you haven't changed set `GOPATH` value:

> ```
> package main
>
> import "fmt"
>
> func main() {
>     fmt.Println("hello world")
> }
> ```

5. run this by `go run test.go`

i hope it works for you!!

Answer (score -1):

Go to https://go.dev/doc/install site.
Click on the “Download 1.21.3” (whatever the latest version you want to install) button.
Download the version using go1.21.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz the link.
Type `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go && sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.21.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz`
Set your environment variables

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=${HOME%}/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
export PATH = $PATH:$HOME
```

Now type `go version` you will get your go version