# Go is printing xgcc version but not go installed version

Tags: go

On `go version` : It prints

```
go version xgcc (Ubuntu 4.9.1-0ubuntu1) 4.9.1 linux/amd64
```

My installed version is the latest one and i.e 1.4.2

which got installed from the tar version : `go1.4.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz`

GO Environmental variables looks exactly like this:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/user/coding/golang/gocnew/goc/bin"
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/user/coding/golang/gocnew/goc"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/home/user/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/home/user/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
TERM="dumb"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

I expect go version to be printed as 1.4.2, so how that can be achieved?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the newest version is being used?

Comment: Yes i myself downloaded and extracted the files from the site : [Golang Downloads](https://golang.org/dl/)

Comment: Check with `which go` what go binary is being used when you type `go version`

Comment: Yes! `$ which go` gives me `/usr/local/go/bin/go` and `/usr/local/go/bin/go version` gives me `go version go1.11.4 linux/amd64`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like you have two versions of Go installed. One from ubuntu package manager and one you installed from source tar.

To confirm kindly try to remove gccgo :

```
sudo apt-get remove gccgo
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and i fixed it by this way:
Access to go folder: /usr/local/go (The installation folder of go)
Execute these commands:

Added by Go Path

`echo 'export GOROOT=/usr/local/go' >> ~/.bashrc`

`echo 'export GOPATH=$HOME/go' >> ~/.bashrc`

`echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin' >> ~/.bashrc`

And then go to the source folder and check go version: 
`go version go1.12.2 linux/amd64` it will be displayed the same version in go folder and you can work with go commands.