# Unable to change GO version in PhotonOS

Tags: go, photon, gvm, photon-os

I have deployed PhotonOS using directions from [photon and VIC configuration](http://cormachogan.com/2016/04/07/getting-started-photon-os-vsphere-integrated-containers/), while running command `docker run -v $(pwd):/go/src/github.com/vmware/vic \-w /go/src/github.com/vmware/vic golang:1.6 make all` 
an Error appears:

> Please install go1.7 (found: go version go1.6.3 linux/amd64)
>
> Makefile:152: recipe for target 'goversion' failed
>
> make: *** [goversion] Error 1

`
to solve it I have tried to update

> go1.6.3 to go1.7 using solution - [changeing go version manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34384978/2653036)

after steps go version is showing go1.4.2, but the previous error still complains on go version 1.6.3.
Also, I have tried to install "gvm" using `bash < <(curl -s -S -L https://raw.github.com/moovweb/gvm/master/binscripts/gvm-installer)` , whenever I try to call `gvm install go1.7` it brings

> -bash: gvm: command not found

whenever I retry running `gvm-installer` it says

> ERROR: Already installed!

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: A `$PATH` issue? I mean, the `gvm` command is not listed in the `PATH` environment variable of the account which tried to access it. Say, for non-root users, `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` are typically *not* listed there. Since I have absolutely zero knowledge about what "PhotonOS" is, I can't really verify this -- make your research.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I'll try to add gvm to $PATH.

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/go/src/github.com/vmware/vic \-w /go/src/github.com/vmware/vic golang:1.7 make all
```

command instead, that will work on PhotonOS

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, will try it.