# All of a sudden go tool: no such tool "compile"

Tags: go

I had installed go on my Ubuntu desktop and it worked fine before I switch off the computer.

Now as I started my machine and resumed my work on the project, I get this

```
$ go build
go tool: no such tool "compile"
go tool: no such tool "compile"
go tool: no such tool "compile"
go tool: no such tool "compile"
go tool: no such tool "compile"
```

When I try to build a project.

The  only thing that I did before poweroff which might have some effect was to install godoc using

```
sudo apt-get install golang-doc
```

I had install go directly by downloading `go1.10.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz` file, not using `apt-get`

go env

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/me/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/me/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build255010769=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

$ go version

```
go version go1.10.1 linux/amd64
```

I can still run comiled go code.

What could have gone wrong here? How can I fix it?

Comment: Is the `compile` program in `GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"`?

Comment: No. `cannot access '/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64': No such file or directory
`

Comment: Right, but how to solve it?

Comment: Post the output from `ls /usr/local/go
`,  `ls /usr/local/go/pkg`, and `ls /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64`.

Comment: Actually, there was not any `/usr/local/go/pkg`. Not sure why? So I just downloaded a new `go1.10.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz` and extracted to `/user/loca/` and that solved the problem. Many thanks for your tip. Please answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I broke my compile, too.  I had modified GOROOT and it immediately broke.  As with Oleg, I was able to correct with `unset GOROOT` (essentially the equivalent of what Oleg did)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `compile` program should be in your `go env` `GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"` directory. If not, download Go, delete `/usr/local/go`, and reinstall Go.

Answer (score 27):

It may seem odd, but running `export GOROOT=` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Somehow this worked for me. It was `GOROOT="/usr/local/opt/go/libexec"` before, and now it is `GOROOT="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.17.1/libexec"` 
(I'm on a Mac running Darwin Arm64 - M1 chip)

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue in my MAC M1.

Previously, I had downloaded it using "brew". I tried downloading it manually and reinstalling it. That worked for me.

go version: 1.18.2
Download: https://go.dev/dl/

Answer (score 2):

On Apple Silicon / M1.

You probably have `GOROOT` maunally set in your `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` to something like `GOROOT="/usr/local/opt/go/libexec"`.

It would now be:

```
export GOROOT=/opt/homebrew/opt/go/libexec
```

### Why?

Brew changed dir from `/usr/local/opt` to `/opt/homebrew/opt` for M1 arm builds.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading `.tar.gz` versus using `apt-get` may cause `go env` values conflicts/overrides. Better to stick to one installation approach.

I had faced a similar problem in Mac.
When I installed Go using `.dmg` (similar to your `.tar.gz` case), it set a completely different value for `GOTOOLDIR`,
versus when I installed Go using `brew install golang` (similar to your `apt-get` case).

**Analysis:**

If you do the following:

```
go env | grep GOTOOLDIR
cd <value of GOTOOLDIR>
ls
```

You should see the following (notice the `compile` binary):

```
addr2line   buildid     cover       fix     objdump     test2jsonapi        
cgo         dist        link        pack    trace
asm         compile     doc         nm      pprof       vet
```

If you don't, then you have probably switched to the wrong/overwritten/earlier Go installation.

**Solution:**

1. If you are using an IDE, it's easy to switch among multiple Go SDKs by going to *Settings* or *Preferences*. Then restart the Terminal in IDE
2. If you are not using an IDE, a simple solution is to uninstall both the Go installations. Then reinstall Go using only one method. And use the same method to install any other Go related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading `go` I started getting this error and updating GOROOT from `/Users/bharkum3/.go` to `/Users/bharkum3/.go/go-1.18.2` worked for me.

Looks like go install is creating a separate folder now for each versions (our script is doing this I guess) and need the above to redirect the compiler to the right version.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, but on a different system than op, windows+cygwin to be exact.

The issue for me was that the files inside the tools folder were not marked as executable.

To solve this:

1. go to the tools directory (see Abhinav Sureka solution)
2. `chmod a+x *`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I installed some go tool using brew (brew install golangci-lint). This result in installing another go binary. I fixed the issue by running

```
brew uninstall go
```

Answer (score 0):

first go with `locate addr2line`
If it will show you
`/usr/lib/go-1.20/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/addr2line`
above line then
copy all content from `linux_amd64` folder to `/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/` folder using below command
`sudo cp linux_amd64/* /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/`

Now try with `go run` or `go build` command it will work

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was that I had installed the `go` binary for the wrong architecture . I needed go1.18.4.darwin.arm64, not go1.18.4.darwin.amd64.

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu 18 specific solution:

- removed manually installed Go SDK and Go SRC
- removed manually set GOROOT variable
- installed Golang package from `golang-backports`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/golang-backports
sudo apt-get install golang-1.15
```

- Updated my `${HOME}/.bashrc` with:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/go-1.15/bin
```

- Rebooted the OS