# Fail to use the Go Delve debugger with VSCode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

This is my first day with the Go language and I wanted to debug a simple REST API.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Homepage EndPoint Hit")
}

func handleRequests() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func main() {   
handleRequests()
}
```

Here is my debug configuration

```
 {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Launch file",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }

    ]
}
```

The `settings.json` is

```
{
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
    "vs-kubernetes": {
        "vscode-kubernetes.helm-path.mac": "/Users/gsinha/.vs-kubernetes/tools/helm/darwin-amd64/helm"
    },
    "go.toolsManagement.autoUpdate": true,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true
}
```

When I try to start a debug session using `F5`, I get this error.

```
 Starting: /Users/gsinha/go/bin/dlv-dap dap --listen=127.0.0.1:54320 --log-dest=3
DAP server listening at: 127.0.0.1:54320
Build Error: go build -o /Users/gsinha/go/src/rest/__debug_bin -gcflags all=-N -l /Users/gsinha/go/src/rest
go tool: no such tool "compile"
go tool: no such tool "compile"
go tool: no such tool "compile"
go tool: no such tool "compile" (exit status 2)
```

I am able to run the application but when I try to start a debug session it fails unexpectedly.

Comment: Please paste your vscode setting.json.

Comment: as suggested by @p1gd0g please share with use the output of `go env`, `go version`, os version and the method used to install the Go compiler. Please also add the settings of VSCode for the go compiler, if relevant, IDK much about this IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `go env`, the `compile` file should be in path `GOTOOLDIR`.
If not, check your go installation.

Maybe helpful: [All of a sudden go tool: no such tool "compile"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182422/all-of-a-sudden-go-tool-no-such-tool-compile)

--- update ---

It should be a go env problem.

Could u check `go env` and `go build` using the vscode internal terminal?

Have u ever chose go sdk version in vscode?

Comment: The compile file is there inside GOTOOLDIR path. I think I have some simple error in settings.

Comment: @EagerLearner Can u build package in your own terminal, not vscode?

Comment: I was able to run go run main.go and go build too from the terminal and it worked fine. It's just the debugging which is causing pain here

Comment: Try to restart from VS Code from the terminal where the path to the `go` binary is correctly in `PATH`.  The extension inherits environment setup from the VS Code, and that can be different from the environment you see from integrated terminals unfortunately. And check `Go: Locate Configured Go Tools` command output to see the environment setup the extension sees.