# Go / golang - does it have equivalent of python "pip install" to install packages?

Tags: go

Have just started learning about Go (do people say "Go" or "Golang"?)

I got the hello world example running. I have my GOROOT AND GOPATH set up.

Now I want to do something bit more advanced, for example open csv file, for which I found a tutorial to do that [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/csv-go)

In order to make this script work, I need the packages that are being imported eg "bufio", "encoding/csv", etc.

Do I have to manually search https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Projects or some other repository, download and unzip these into my GOPATH "pkg" directory?

Or does Go/Golang have something equivalent to Python's "pip install" that would do this for me?

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/csv"
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

func main() {
    // Load a TXT file.
    f, _ := os.Open("C:\\Users\\bb\\Documents\\Dropbox\\Data\\bc hydro tweets\\bchtweets.csv")

    // Create a new reader.
    r := csv.NewReader(bufio.NewReader(f))
    for {
    record, err := r.Read()
    // Stop at EOF.
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    // Display record.
    // ... Display record length.
    // ... Display all individual elements of the slice.
    fmt.Println(record)
    fmt.Println(len(record))
    for value := range record {
        fmt.Printf("  %v\n", record[value])
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: The assumption I  did not do any research is incorrect. I did and after 60 minutes asked an earnest question and received two good answers. What else is SO for?

Comment: Genaki, forgive me, but on [golang.org->Documents->Learning Go the second document is "How to Write Go Code"](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) which has a section called [Remote packages](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#remote) which deals with exactly your question. Can we agree that your research was probably a bit fluffy? ;) Read the docs. Thoroughly. Really, they are worth it.

Comment: I did see that. One of it's first sentences "An import path can describe" makes it seem "optional" or "alternate" method of getting packages and method appeared reliant on GitHub and Mercurial which also makes it seem exceptional. I earnestly needed more. Patrick's answer nailed it for me unambiguously which is what I needed. Earnest question after earnest research. Frankly I think question is good as it relates Go to Python (cool to see Glide mentioned which supports benefit). Net effect of negative points will be to drive people away from this question which now has good replies.

Comment: Well, people are free to voice their opinion. Do not kill the messenger ;)

Comment: And messenger shouldn't kill the message either ; )

Comment: Only answering your first doubt. The name of the language is just Go, but you use golang on online documentation to allow proper search

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go has `go get` which is similar to `pip install` in Python. ([ref](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies))

UPDATE: Starting in Go 1.17, installing executables with `go get` is deprecated. `go install` may be used instead.([ref](https://go.dev/doc/go-get-install-deprecation))

Answer (score 5):

Read every single line of this beautiful documentation's section: https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Organization

BTW, all packages you have in your import section are from standard library. So you don't have to install anything for this example.

Best way to install a package is `go get` which simply clones a git repo to your `$GOPATH/src` and you should stick to it as long as you can.
If you **must** use some package version you can create fork for a specified commit and `go get` that fork or use one of many vendoring toolds https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PackageManagementTools

Comment: Ah ok I see those packages in the GOPATH src folder. I was expecting to get them into my app's GOROOT/myapp/src folder. Getting clearer thanks.

Comment: @genoki go trough that Organization doc and all should be clear. I don't know why you expected the lib to be there. You can read about GOROOT and GOPATH there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970390/what-should-be-the-values-of-gopath-and-goroot

Answer (score 4):

The [Glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide) package manager is maybe your closest option to pip. You have config (and lock) files, can specify versions, etc.

Until Go 1.6 is out you'll need to set the environment variable `GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1` for the `go` tool to pickup the packages in the `vendor/` folder. In Go 1.6 this will be on by default. Glide stores packages in a `vendor/` folder instead of the `GOPATH` (even though the root project needs to be in the `GOPATH`) so that different applications can have and regularly use different versions of dependencies.

If you want something a little different there are [numerous package managers listed on the wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PackageManagementTools).

*Disclosure: I'm on of Glide's developers. Pip was one of the inspirations for it.*