# How to confirm that $GOPATH and $GOROOT are properly set?

Tags: go

This is not a repeat of this question:

[what should be the values of GOPATH and GOROOT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970390/what-should-be-the-values-of-gopath-and-goroot)

I don't want to know what the values should be.  I want to know what I should see when I type `ls $GOROOT` or `ls $GOPATH` into console.  I'm pretty sure I set things up wrong following a tutorial almost a year ago, and I want to be able to confirm that these two are pointing to where they should be by simply checking that what they point to looks right.

Here's where I am right now.  It looks like `$GOROOT` is pointing nowhere.  I'm pretty sure it should be pointing at `usr/local/go`, but it would be a lot easier to confirm if I knew what the expected result of `ls $GOROOT` is supposed to be.

As for `$GOPATH` I'm not totally sure if my "workspace" is where all my go code is, or maybe just the github stuff, or maybe the particular folder I'm working within.  I know it's supposed to point to my "work space," but I don't know what that work space I'm looking for looks like.

```
Sephs-MBP:ThumbzArt seph$ $GOROOT
Sephs-MBP:ThumbzArt seph$ $GOPATH
-bash: /Users/seph/code/golang: is a directory
Sephs-MBP:ThumbzArt seph$ ls $GOROOT
Bman.jpg            README.md           ThumbzArt.sublime-workspacescripts              thumbzart.go
LICENSE.md          ThumbzArt.sublime-project   public              templates           ticktock.go
Sephs-MBP:ThumbzArt seph$ $GOPATH
-bash: /Users/seph/code/golang: is a directory
Sephs-MBP:ThumbzArt seph$ ls $GOPATH
-   bin p   pkg src
Sephs-MBP:ThumbzArt seph$ ls /usr/local/go
AUTHORS     CONTRIBUTORS    PATENTS     VERSION     bin     doc     lib     pkg     src
CONTRIBUTING.md LICENSE     README.md   api     blog        favicon.ico misc        robots.txt  test
Sephs-MBP:ThumbzArt seph$
```

I know this question seems ridiculous, but it's hard to confirm things for which you have no expected results.

Thank you

```
Sephs-MBP:streak seph$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/seph/code/golang"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=""
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"

Sephs-MBP:streak seph$ go version
go version go1.5.2 darwin/amd64

Sephs-MBP:streak seph$ which go
/usr/local/go/bin/go
```

Comment: Don't set GOROOT. Once you set GOPATH, the go tools with create what's necessary. You don't need to do anything extra.

Comment: What "silent failure" are you getting? We need to know what the problem actually is you want to solve.

Comment: I'm getting a silent failure, and I haven't touched anything since my last use.  I know that I used to have a little script I would copy and paste that set $GOPATH or $GOROOT or $PATH or maybe all three.  But with no error being thrown, it's really hard to tell what's missing.

Comment: There are no "silent failures" from the go tool if it does anything at all. Use the `-x` option of you want to see all the commands executed.

Comment: okay.  nothing happens.  it just hangs there.  And I'm okay with figuring things out from there.  I just wanted to know what the expected results of `ls $GOPATH` and `ls $GOROOT` are

Comment: I'm not expecting you guys to fix my problem for me.  I'm asking for some confirmation on data.  A confirmation which should probably be easy to find.

Comment: it appears that `ls $GOROOT` is different from `ls usr/local/go`  though `go env` says `GOROOT="/usr/local/go"`

Comment: Ofc it differs: `$GOROOT` ist not set so `ls $GOROOT` outputs the content of your working dir. Is go really the go from /usr/local/go (`which go`). Can you build your sourcefile?

Comment: By the way: What does your program do? Sure that your program does exit?

Comment: I added `which go`.  I'm not sure which sourcefile you're speaking of.  I have a simple `helloworld.go` that ran fine.  I have another project which returns no errors and just kind of hangs when I run `go run thumbzart.go [-x]`.  Bot of these projects worked fine last time I touched them.  The program hosts a website.  Is there another source file I should build?

Comment: What i think: go is setup ok,  thumbzart.go not.

Comment: That's what I think too.  I just hadn't touched thumbzart.go, and I used to do something with the paths every time I ran it.  I wanted to confirm it wasn't my set up, and that seems to be confirmed.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: See also: [How to show an environment variable's current value?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244323/how-to-show-an-environment-variables-current-value) on [unix.SE] Stack Exchange

Answer (score -4, accepted):

EDIT:  Another very useful feature I just stumbled across is this: `go help gopath`.  This should have probably been somebodies answer.

The folder `$GOPATH` points to should like this:

```
Sephs-MBP:streak seph$ ls $GOPATH
-   bin p   pkg src
```

`$GOROOT`, on the other hand, will yield unexpected results if you use `ls $GOROOT` as compared to `ls $GOPATH`.  This is because `$GOROOT` is not set within this context, I think.

```
Sephs-MBP:helloworld seph$ ls $GOROOT
helloworld.go
```

If you use `go env` you'll see the true nature of `$GOROOT`

```
Sephs-MBP:streak seph$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/seph/code/golang"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"            //this is where it actually points
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=""
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-    arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

And if you get the result of `$GOROOT` from `go env` and do `ls` you should see something like this:

```
Sephs-MBP:streak seph$ ls /usr/local/go
AUTHORS     CONTRIBUTORS    PATENTS     VERSION     bin     doc         lib     pkg     src
CONTRIBUTING.md LICENSE     README.md   api     blog        favicon.ico misc        robots.txt  test
```

If all of these things check out, then your `$GOPATH` and `$GOROOT` are properly set.

Comment: As i wrote above: Since `$GOROOT` is not set `ls $GOROOT` becomes `ls`: It prints your working directory.

Comment: @0x434D53 Yeah, that's why the invented `echo $GOROOT` :-)