# Go installing package /usr/bin/go not a directory

Tags: go

Im trying to install a Go package but having the following error.

Here is my GOPATH

```
p@p-ubuntu:~/ba/docker-lvm-plugin$ echo $GOPATH
/usr/bin/go
```

Package install

```
p@p-ubuntu:~/ba/docker-lvm-plugin$ go get github.com/Sirupsen/logrus
    package github.com/Sirupsen/logrus: mkdir /usr/bin/go: not a directory
```

Comment: Can someone give some insight into why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 9):

Your GOPATH is wrong. It should not be the path to the go binary, it should be the path to the root of your go project directory, which should contain `src`, `pkg`, and `bin` subdirectories. See [what should be the values of GOPATH and GOROOT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970390/what-should-be-the-values-of-gopath-and-goroot)

Comment: Just as a side note, the most common GOPATH seems to be `~/go`.

Answer (score 0):

please change the GOBIN to available path, for example $GOPATH/bin, or $GOROOT/bin

you can see GOBIN with `go env`