# Golang Facebook Package Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, go

I am trying to get friendlist from Facebook Messenger in golang using REST API. For this, I tried to import package `github.com/huandu/facebook`. But while running the code it gave an error:

`package context: unrecognized import path "context" (import path does not begin with hostname)`

Here is the import statement (as mentioned in godoc https://godoc.org/github.com/huandu/facebook):

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/huandu/facebook"
)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing Wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your Go environment is setup correctly, especially your `$GOPATH` and `$GOROOT`.

https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH

Comment: My $GOPATH is set to $HOME/go and $GOROOT is set to /usr/lib/go-1.6 and it works well for other packages.

Comment: @Amandeepkaur: go1.6 is out of date. Update your go version, and do not set GOROOT.

Comment: Agreed with @JimB, your `$GOROOT` looks suspicious. [Look at this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970390/what-should-be-the-values-of-gopath-and-goroot#10847122)