# command 'go.tools.install' not found

Tags: windows, go, installation

I am trying to install Go tools in my VS Code editor and when I select the View, CMD, Install and select Go: Install/Update tools, I get this -> "command 'go.tools.install' not found"
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

As seen in [Microsoft/vscode-go issue 755](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/755):

> For all guys who are stuck with command '`go.tools.install`' not found problem on Windows.
>
> Check if `%GOPATH%\bin` is in your `PATH` environment variable.
> After half and an hour I finally figured out that `PATH` remains unchanged if you try to change it like `set PATH=%PATH%`.... You need explicitly change it in your system settings.

With recent Go installation, make sure `GOROOT` reference your Go installation folder.
I also like to set `go.goroot` to that folder in the settings of VSCode.
You don't need `GOPATH`: it defaults to `%USERPROFILE%\go`: make sure `%USERPROFILE%\go\bin` is in your PATH, before launching VSCode.

- unzip [go1.13.6.windows-amd64.zip](https://dl.google.com/go/go1.13.6.windows-amd64.zip) anywhere (not in `%USERPROFILE%\go`, since it is reserved for `GOPATH`)
- set GOROOT to `C:\path\to\go` (where you just uncompressed the Go archive)
- add `%GOROOT%\bin` to `%PATH%`

Comment: Added it to my PATH and got this: Failed to run "go env" to find GOPATH as the "go" binary cannot be found in either GOROOT(undefined) or PATH(C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intuit\QBPOSSDKRuntime;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Ruby24-x64\bin;C:\Users\family\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin; C:\Users\family\go\bin)

Comment: @DougHughes81 Set in your user environment variable `GOROOT` to where Go is installed. And add `%GOROOT%\bin` to your path. Note: `C:\Users\family\go` is not `GOROOT`, it is the default value for `GOPATH`.

Comment: As in which of these paths? C:\Users\Family\AppData\Roaming\Code\User
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe
Sorry for being so naive, but I am when it comes to Go

Comment: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User...no \bin there

Comment: Simply unzip go wherever you want, and add that path + bin

Comment: Worked perfectly!! Thank you kind sir :)

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was on **Ubuntu** and installed go using **snap** so I did the following:

1. Uninstall go from snap
   `sudo snap remove go`
2. Download go from the original source: `https://go.dev/doc/install`
3. Install go as recommended in the source e.g.:
   `rm -rf /usr/local/go && tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.19.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz`
4. Run the following to add the environment variables in the `.bashrc`:

```
echo export GOROOT=/usr/local/go >> ~/.bashrc
echo export GOPATH=\$HOME/go >> ~/.bashrc
echo export PATH=\$PATH:\$GOROOT/bin:\$GOPATH/bin >> ~/.bashrc
```

Note: Setting `$GOROOT` variable is obsolete in recent versions as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68854441/2110865)

5. Restart the VS Code to read the environment variables set above
6. In VSCode press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and run again the `GO: Install/Update tools`, install everything selecting the checkboxes and you are good to GO!