# Not able to import Go packages

Tags: go

I want to use this package: `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`

I tried with:

```
go get -u github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

It went right, but when I'm importing the package and running the code its gives me an error:

```
main.go:12:2: no required module provides package github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'
```

Comment: ‘_go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory_’ is a clue. [Learn to use Go modules.](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules)

Comment: then how to make go.mod file?

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-init

Comment: «then how to make go.mod file?» — It's the 2nd tutorial right there [on the official site's page dedicated to documentation](https://golang.org/doc/).

Answer (score 4):

In project root directory run

```
go mod init example.com/your-project-name
```

It will create `go.mod` file

```
module example.com/your-project-name

go 1.15
```

Then run

```
go get -u github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As rustyx said in the comment, this is a deprecated approach and you might want to consider newer ones

You can do without the `go.mod` if your `GOROOT` and `GOPATH` environment variables are setted correctly
To do so, you can refer to
[What should be the values of GOPATH and GOROOT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970390/what-should-be-the-values-of-gopath-and-goroot)

Also, you need to ensure that your IDE/text editor also recognize those two variables.
*Note: In the case of an IDE (such as Goland), you might need to set it up manually. In the case of a text editor (ex: vscode), you can simply reload your project and it should do the trick.*

Once this is done, you can validate that the content of your $GOPATH/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/ is present. If not, you can rerun your `go get -u github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` command, reload your editor, and you should be alright

Comment: No no, don't use GOPATH anymore. It's legacy. The linked thread is outdated, except for **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68319410/485343)**.